# Clear Text Content Controls in Word Without Deleting VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a document in Word that allows the user to enter information on page 1 and through use of text controls, bookmarks, and cross references, the text they entered in will be auto filled in various places throughout the document.

To do this, I'm clicking Developer > Plain Text Content Control, and letting the user enter in their information.

What I'd like to implement is a button that essentially clears all the information that the user may have entered previously into these Text Content Control boxes. I do not want to delete the content controls, because this will screw up all of my mapping and I will need to re-do them.

Is there a way in VBA to loop through all of my Text Content Controls and add the default text "Click or tap here to enter text"?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably all you need:

```
Sub ClearCCs()
  Dim CC As ContentControl
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
      CC.Range.Text = ""
  Next CC
End Sub
```

You might have to get a little more complicated if any CCs are in text boxes, frames or other odd locations.